# Why do we assume that V is zero?

Tags: voltage, diodes

In the photo below, under the diode (D2), we're given V and to help solve for current, V is equal to zero in the solution. How can we assume V=0 if it's not given in the question?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diodes D1 and D2 will each have a very similar voltage drop across them. Therefore they will cancel each other out, and as D1 is connected to 0V, there will also be 0V below D2.

Comment: I see, so essentially you look at D1 and see it grounded which gives the assumption that V2 should also be grounded. Thanks.

Comment: Well you also need to check if D1 is forward biased or not. The resistor values and voltages matter here. Change that top resistor to 20K and try again...